# What would be the inverse of the list() function

Tags: python

Say that you had this:
Laugh = 'hehe'
The practicality of this of example doesn't really matter but if you wanted to put laugh into a list by doing: laugh = list(laugh) and you do laugh[1] = 'a'. How would you put laugh into 'hahe'?

Comment: `''.join(your_list)` assuming `your_list` came from a listified string.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to convert a list into a string, use `''.join`:

```
laugh = 'hehe'
laugh = list(laugh)
laugh[1] = 'a'

laugh = ''.join(laugh)
```

This is better than other methods such as using a `for`-loop:

```
new_laugh = ''
for c in laugh:
    new_laugh += c
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (using just the `+` operator - in case you want to have a user defined function to do get the task done) would be to add the components of the list into one string:

```
def string_to_list(L):
    S = ""
    for i in L:
        S = S + str(L)
    return S
string_to_list(laugh)
```

You can also use the `join()` function, to do the same:

```
Laugh = ''.join(laugh)
```

Comment: Really, `+` is just as much a built-in function as `str.join` is. There is no reason to write that loop.

Comment: The `+` is not a function, it is an operator. And, I have specified both ways... 
Just gave the options (that I know about)

Comment: Yes, but it’s implemented by an add function built in in to the type.

Comment: Oh! Okay.. Fair point. I just meant to say that I would always prefer `2+3` rather than `sum(2,3)`. Maybe that wasn't clear. But, thanks. I will edit the answer accordingly

Comment: My main point is that while the `for` loop is useful for describing how `join` works, you would never actually want to use it in preference to `join`.